# When does a property get called?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a confusion on some piece of code.

Inside a class I have a property

```
Class A
{
  ClassB objB;

  public int TimedValue
  {
    objB.Timer;
  }
}

Inside classB I have

classB
{
 public int Timer
 {
  get
  {
   // get time value using some algorithm....
  }
 }
}
```

My confusion is that I place breakpoints inside the getters, but I dont see the program flow there and stop! Although I see an object being created and full populated with the TimedValue when I look at it in debug mode inside a watch window. Am I missing something on properties?

EDIT: So, ColinE guided me through the right steps, except I could not find the option there. Here is the screen shot where of where it was suppose to be,
[image]

My screen shot

[image]
I guess this is a VS bug. Anyway Just posted this so that anyone with team system 2008 should make a note of this :)

Comment: Do you have "step over properties" enabled in visual studio?

Comment: @Wajih: should you code be `objB.Timer;`?

Comment: @Max, let me check, did not realize there was an option like that!

Comment: @Neil, just a typing error, fixed now.

Comment: Is `public int TimedValue{ objB.Timer; }` a method or a property !!

Comment: is this a new 2010 notation with the property directly inside the other property or is the getter / setter missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the debugger is configures to step over properties, so your breakpoint will never be 'hit. Ensure that the following checkbox is not checked:

```
Tools => Options => Debugging => General => Step over properties and operators
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accessing the Field `Time` (if that's not a typo in your question and you've omitted that part in your post), not the property `Timer` on `classB`.

Comment: True, looks like he's edited his post, so he did just re-type the code (which could have meant typos were present).